# JComboBox wont appear. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am having issues with my code and it seems that the JComboBox will appear and vanish whenever it likes. I have had instances of when the JComboBox works and then simply closing and relaunching the program causes it to stop working again. What is going on?

```
class FutoshikiGUI extends JFrame {
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    public FutoshikiGUI() {
        super("Futoshiki");

        //setup standard GUI parameters
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(600,600);
        add(main);

        //initialise other GUI components
        initPanel();
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        //prepare main panel
        main.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        main.setBackground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));

        //create and prepare title
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Futoshiki");
        title.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        main.add(title, gbc);

        //create and prepare combobox
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        String[] diff = {"Easy", "Med", "Hard"};
        JComboBox difficulty = new JComboBox(diff);
        difficulty.setSelectedIndex(0);
        main.add(difficulty);
    }
```

Comment: Don't make your `JFrame` visible before  all components have been added.

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it was a nooby mistake but didn't know it would be that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Also, call `add(main)` after `initPanel()` :)

Comment: Sweet thanks, was stuck on that for ages. You can write and answer if you like and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3):

You should call `setVisible(true)` only once all components have been added to the `JFrame`.

Also, call `add(main)` after `initPanel()`, to be sure that the `JPanel` is also ready :

```
public FutoshikiGUI() {
    super("Futoshiki");

    //setup standard GUI parameters
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    //initialise other GUI components
    initPanel();

    add(main);

    setResizable(false);
    setSize(600,600);

    setVisible(true);
}
```